# KoJs: bind a dynamic number of text boxes to elements of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I have a front-end which allows for adding and removing of  text boxes suing the foreach binding. A text box looks something like this

```
<div id="dynamic-filters" data-bind="foreach: filterList">
        <p>
            <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: $parent.values[$index()], autoComplete: { options: $parent.options}, attr: { id : 'nameInput_' + $index() }"/>
        </p>
 </div>
```

What I want to do, as shown in the code above is to bind each of these dynamically generated text boxes to an element in the array using the $index() context provided by knockout.js

However it doesn't work for me, my `self.values=ko.observableArray([])` doesn't change when the text boxes change.

My question is, if I want to have a way to bind these dynamically generated text boxes, is this the right way to do it? If it is how do I fix it? If it's not, what should I do instead?

Thanks guys!

**EDIT 1**
the values array is an observable so I thought I should unwrap it before use. I changed the code to

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: $parent.values()[$index()], autoComplete: { options: $parent.options}, attr: { id : 'nameInput_' + $index() }"/>
```

This works in a limited way. When I add or change the content of text boxes, the array changes accordingly. However when I delete an element it fails in two ways:

- If I delete the last item, the array simply doesn't change
- If I delete an item in between, everything is shifted back

I suppose I have to add a function that changes the text-input value before destroying the text box itself.

Any help or advice on how to do this?

Comment: You have not mentioned what is purpose of `filterList`. You have a `foreach` binding for it, but you have not used any property of items of `filterList` within the `foreach` block. If you want `values` array to be updated, why not use `foreach: values`?

Comment: Create a minimal [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) if possible. It will be easy to understand what you're trying and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can't make fiddle at work but the reason why I need the filterList is because it holds the entire <p></p> component with a few text boxes and a button, which I don't include in my code example. Sorry that it caused certain confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking the array of values and mapping it to some kind of model first, then dumping it into the **filterList ko.observableArray.** It can be as complex or as simple as need be.

That way you have direct access to those properties at the ko foreach: level instead of having to do the goofy index access.

I've added a simple knockout component example as well to show you what can be achieved.

```js
var PageModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  var someArrayOfValues = [{label: 'label-1', value: 1},{label: 'label-2', value: 2},{label: 'label-3', value: 3},{label: 'label-4', value: 4}];
  
  this.SimpleInputs = ko.observableArray(_.map(someArrayOfValues, function(data){
    return new SimpleInputModel(data);
  }));
  this.AddSimpleInput = function(){
    self.SimpleInputs.push(new SimpleInputModel({value:'new val', label:'new label'}));
  };
  this.RemoveSimpleInput = function(obj){
    self.SimpleInputs.remove(obj);
  }
}

var SimpleInputModel = function(r) {
  this.Value = ko.observable(r.value);
  this.Label = r.label;
};

var SimpleInputComponent = function(params){
  this.Id = makeid();
  this.Label = params.label;
  this.Value = params.value;
  function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
  }
}

ko.components.register('input-component', {
  viewModel: SimpleInputComponent,
  template: '<label data-bind="text: Label, attr: {for: Id}"></label><input type="text" data-bind="textInput: Value, attr: {id: Id}" />'
})

window.model = new PageModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko if: SimpleInputs -->
  <h3>Simple Inputs</h3>
  <!-- ko foreach: SimpleInputs -->
    <input-component params="value: Value, label: Label"></input-component>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.RemoveSimpleInput">X</button>
    <br>
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<button data-bind="click: AddSimpleInput">Add Input</button>
```

EDIT (7/16/2020):

> Mind explaining this without requiring lodash? I literally googled "how to lodash map using plain javascript". Excellent answer otherwise! – CarComp

In this scenario the lodash _.map method could be overkill **unless** you are executing the script in an environment that does not have native support for the [vanilla array map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). If you have support for the vanilla method, go ahead and use that. The map method essentially iterates over each array using the method it is handed to return a transformed array of the original items. Implementation of vanilla code would look like so.

```
this.SimpleInputs = ko.observableArray(someArrayOfValues.map(function(data) {
  return new SimpleInputModel(data);
}));
```

Here we are taking the values of `someArrayOfValues` and telling it to use each item to build a new SimpleInputModel and return it using that item data. `[SimpleInputModel, SimpleInputModel, SimpleInputModel, SimpleInputModel]` is what the new array turns into after mapping. Each of these items has all the functionality described in the SimpleInputModel class, Value and Label.

So with the new array you could, if you wanted, access the values like this as well `self.SimpleInputs[0].Value()` or `self.SimpleInputs[0].Label`

Hope that helps to clarify.

Comment: Mind explaining this without requiring lodash?  I literally googled "how to lodash map using plain javascript".  Excellent answer otherwise!